# How do I make the inner text of a select option uppercase?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

my question is quite straight forward: I have a select containing multiple options, all I'd like to do is have the inner text of these (a.k.a. the displayed text in the dropdown) be completely uppercase.

Currently I looks like this (compiled html):

```
<select class="select required form-control" id="home_region" name="home[region]">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="ag">Ag</option>
<option value="ar">Ar</option>
<option value="ai">Ai</option>
<option value="be">Be</option>
...
```

And my Ruby on Rails Code (Rails 4 using Simple Form Gem) is:

```
f.input :region, collection: Home::Region::REGIONS.map { |region| [ t(region, scope: 'regions'), region] }, label: 'Region'
```

The 'Home::Regions::REGIONS' being mapped above is simple an Array filled with the regions (sam format as is in the value tag of the corresponding html option).

It doesn't matter to me how it's made uppercase, css, jquery, ruby, anything that works is fine :)

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: @emmanuel : Damn, using select#home_regions worked! I was trying to change the individual options with css before, which failed. Thanks so much for the quick answer m8!

Answer (score 2):

If the looks is what you're after, you'd be best off using CSS:

```
#home_region option {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest solution for this using CSS text transform property.

`#`home_region {

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
 function upperConvrt()
    {
        $("#home_region option").each(function()
        {
            $(this).text($(this).text().toUpperCase())
        });
    }
```

Call the above after the page is loaded.